# python pandas - get piece of dataframe based on the values in column of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have `df1`:

```
   m  n
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
```

and `df2`:

```
   n  k
0  1  z
1  2  g
```

I just want to get the piece of `df1` where the values of column 'n' are the same as those present in `df2`:

```
   m  n
0  a  1
1  b  2
```

What's the best way to do this? It seemed trivial beforehand but then surprisingly nothing I tried worked. For example I tried

```
df1[df1["n"] == df2["n"]]
```

but this gave me

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `isin`

```
df1.loc[df1.n.isin(df2.n),:]
```

Comment: Wen! Always the first to help :D Thanks, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor Just have time check the question queue , and pick the questioner which I know firstly .. :-), it is obviously , I know you :-)

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor besure to upvote and accept this solution.